# Obsf4 bridges with ipv6 support?

Tags: configuration, tails, network-configuration, ipv6

Where can I find obfs4 bridges with ipv6 support for Tails?
This link doesn't work:

https://bridges.torproject.org/options

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately an old issue. Moved and closed several times but still not resolved:
[Distribute IPv6 bridges through bridges.torproject.org.](https://gitlab.torproject.org/legacy/trac/-/issues/26542)
[BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/options)  so far only works for IPv6 vanilla bridges.
[I have 2 IPv6 obfs4 bridges running in Germany.](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search/TorOrDie4privacyNET) If you want the IP's mail me (+gpg-key) or use keybase.